# How to decode / read US Veterans Bureau Form 7202?

Tags: united-states, military, world-war-one, records

In doing some family background research, I came across an old military service record which says it is a "Form 7202 - Rev. Sept., 1927". I would like to decipher the meanings of the various codes to perhaps help me find some information about this family member (which no one can tell me anything about.)

I have done three different passes of blurring in order to protect the details, and then typed a **description** of the fields I found over top of the blur (without using the actual values), and posted the image here.

[image: Form 7202]

After a lot of failed Googling, I thought perhaps someone here might be able to point me to a resource that can decipher the meanings of the various codes on here.

The "N" in "N-NNNNN" means "numbers"; the two letters are hand-written in what appears to be pencil

Comment: Do the patterns of numbers/letters match those on [this example of Form 7202](https://images.findagrave.com/photos/2016/43/65871465_1455393359.jpg) on findagrave?

Comment: For questions related to genealogical research, you'll likely find more expert advice on the [Geneology.SE site](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @sempaiscuba Yes, it looks pretty close - is there a key for decoding those somewhere?

Comment: @T.E.D. Thanks - I hadn't really considered it so much a genealogical question as a "how to decode historical documents" question, but I'll try there as well.

Comment: @TML - [please do not respond in comments; the question should contain all the information needed to answer the question.](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3882/1401)  Comment streams are a disincentive to answering the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an index card from the 'United States Veterans Administration Master Index'. The collection from 1917 - 1940 is available to [search and view online at FamilySearch](https://www.familysearch.org/search/collection/2968245).

From the linked [description for that collection](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/United_States,_Veterans_Administration_Master_Index_(FamilySearch_Historical_Records)), the following codes are listed:

- K - Life Insurance
- A - Adjusted Compensation (Bonus)
- T - War Risk Insurance
- R - Rehabilitation
- Ct -WWI Certificate
- I -Permanent Disability

An example of a completed card can be seen here:

[image: sample record card]

---

Your surmise that Sn was the serial number is correct. This can be seen in the example of Clarence Thomae, from the example above, by examining extracts from his New York Abstract of World War I Military Service:

[image: Extract from Clarence Thomae's New York Abstract of World War I Military Service]

and his application for a Purple Heart:

[image: Extract from Clarence Thomae's application for a Purple Heart]

where we see that his Army serial number was indeed *1,209,111*.

---

[This series of blog posts](http://www.ancestraldiscoveries.com/2016/03/) by the professional genealogist, Janice M. Sellers, includes the [pro-forma postcard Form 7201](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-VLQQRmxpAzM/VuuEdLUIbFI/AAAAAAAAHc4/yoPkQpAEJJYTxKGQO9pTl9opSUYQ9u9kA/s1600/Emma-VetClaim1927PC-Back-LR.jpg). Based on that,  I think that the first code, C (or *XC* in the example above), was the claim number assigned to that individual.

In the example of Clarence Harry Thomae above, the claim number would thus be *XC 248 113*.

Answer (score 0):

This document has the exact meaning of each of the code letters on the card https://www.archives.gov/files/calendar/genealogy-fair/2018/6-csar-handout3.pdf